# How to use artifactId with different filename in dependencies

Tags: maven, dependencies, artifactory

Using Artifactory and Maven, how can one refer to a dependency with the correct group/artifactId/version but use a filname that differs from the artifactId-version.end style?

The problem comes with a dll that cannot be renamed, and the mandatory? Artifactory naming convention.

---

**edit**
found one possible expensive way for this specific problem where the filename cannot include the dash-sign: creating a new Artifactory repository layout for which the pro-version is needed - so unfortunately, that is not an option!

---

**partly solution for jUnit tests**
using the maven-dependency-plugin and the maven-surefire-plugins one can make jUnits work. unfortunately, it does not solve the problem that the specific `sapjco3.dll` cannot be found when deployed within a war to a server.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>sapjco</groupId>
                                <artifactId>sapjco3</artifactId>
                                <version>3.0.7</version>
                                <type>dll</type>
                                <classifier>win32</classifier>
                                <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                        <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <systemProperties>
                    <property>
                        <name>java.library.path</name>
                        <value>${project.build.directory}/lib</value>
                    </property>
                </systemProperties>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maven does not care for filenames, it cares for their coordinates. Add your DLL correctly to your remote repo and maven will do the rest.
A dependency snippet might be:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.company</groupId>
  <artifactId>my.artifact</atifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <type>dll</type>
  <classifier>win32</classifier>
</dependency>
```

After you have done this, use either [`dependency:copy-dependencies`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-project-dependencies.html) or [`dependency:copy`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html) to change the filename at build time.

Comment: yes, the problem is that I cannot add sapjco3.dll as sapjco-3.dll, hence the need for the filename to stay exactly as it is, not according to Artifactory standard..

Comment: Please specify your build in more detail. Who is exactly consuming the DLL? A Java app? If yes, this can be parameterized.
Is there no native Java implementation of the SAP Java connector?

Comment: its a java webapp, using classes from sapjco3.jar with depends unfortunately onto sapjco3.dll in exact that way.

Comment: Ok, you have defined a dep von sapjco.jar which in turn depends on the dll, right?

Comment: hm, I tried using maven-dependency-plugin and the stripVersion tag, unfortunately that does only work within the same project, not when included within another jar/war..

Comment: this way (by copy/stripVersion) I am able to run junits correclty with the maven-surefire-plugin ..but no success with the acutal war.

Comment: If it is included, exclude this transitive dependency and you have full control. If the DLL is embedded in a JAR, you have to remove it from that JAR.

Comment: I would only embedd it so that I have it with stripped Version; sapjco3.jar is unfortunately no Maven project, so I cant rely on it to care about its dependency to the sapjco3.dll - Ill post my solution for the jUnit in any case.

Comment: This is not true. You can add sapjco3.jar in your repo and with an appropriate POM it can depend on the sapjco3.dll.

Comment: one has no time for anything ..so at last: as problems with re-deployments and the dll-loading arose, the dll was finally put into a tomcat shared dir for the actual deployment. for the rest the dependency-plugin will do - so thanks for the help!